# Pythonic way to compute all combinations of products

Tags: python, combinatorics

Say I have a list of prime numbers [ 2,3,5 ] and I would like to get a list (or an iterator) of all N^3 such products:

```
pow( 2, 0 ) * pow( 3, 0 ) * pow( 5, 0 ) 
pow( 2, 1 ) * pow( 3, 0 ) * pow( 5, 0 ) 
pow( 2, 0 ) * pow( 3, 1 ) * pow( 5, 0 ) 
pow( 2, 0 ) * pow( 3, 0 ) * pow( 5, 1 ) 
pow( 2, 1 ) * pow( 3, 1 ) * pow( 5, 0 ) 
pow( 2, 0 ) * pow( 3, 1 ) * pow( 5, 1 ) 
pow( 2, 1 ) * pow( 3, 0 ) * pow( 5, 1 ) 
[...]
pow( 2, N-1 ) * pow( 3, N-1 ) * pow( 5, N-1 )
```

What is the pythonic way to do that? (in the case of the list of length L)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations will come in handy

Comment: Does it have to be in this order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got you right. Check this(N=3):

```
from itertools import product
from operators import mul

primes = [2,3,5]
n = 3

sets = product(*[[(i,j) for j in range(n)] for i in primes])
# Now 'sets' contains all the combinations you want. If you just wanted pow(i,j), write i**j instead and skip the map in the next enumeration
# list(sets)
#[((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 0)), 
# ((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 1)), 
# ((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 2)), 
#  ... ... ...
# ((2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 0)), 
# ((2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 1)), 
# ((2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 2))]

productlist = []
for t in sets:
    productlist.append(reduce(mul,map(lambda tp:tp[0]**tp[1],t)))

# now productlist contains the multiplication of each n(=3) items:
#[1, 5, 25, 3, 15, 75, 9, 45, 225, 2, 10, 50, 6, 30, 150, 18, 90, 450, 4, 20, 100, 12, 60, 300, 36, 180, 900]
# pow( 2, 0 ) * pow( 3, 0 ) * pow( 5, 0 ) = 1
# pow( 2, 0 ) * pow( 3, 0 ) * pow( 5, 1 ) = 5
# pow( 2, 0 ) * pow( 3, 0 ) * pow( 5, 2 ) = 25
# .... ...
```

Alternatively a one liner could be:

```
productlist = [reduce(mul,t) for t in product(*[[i**j for j in range(n)] for i in primes])]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
from itertools import product
from operator import mul

def all_products(l, k):
    for t in product(*[[(p, e) for e in range(k)] for p in l]):
        yield reduce(mul, [x[0] ** x[1] for x in t], 1)
```

The key is the use of [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Usage:

```
for prod in all_products([2, 3, 5], 3):
    print prod
```

This will give you all products of the form `2^a0 * 3^a1 * 5^a2` where `0 <= aj < 3`.